# how to set realtime index attribute type

Tags: sphinx

I have an index where I would like insert, update and delete rows with realtime index but a index_rt wrong works.

It's a common index config:

```
index jobResumeIndex
{
    source          = jobResumeSource
    path            = {{path_to_data}}/{{data_file_name}}/jobResumeIndex
    morphology      = stem_enru
    charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+401->U+0435, U+451->U+0435
    min_prefix_len = 3
    #min_infix_len = 3
    index_exact_words = 1
    expand_keywords = 1
}
```

and it is a real time config:

```
index jobResumeRT
{
    type            = rt
    source          = jobResumeSource
    path            = {{path_to_data}}/{{data_file_name}}/jobResume

    #Список полей для записи
    rt_field = post
    rt_field = wage
    rt_field = currency_id
    rt_field = tariff_rate_id
    rt_field = business_trip_id
    rt_field = work_experience_id
    rt_field = citizenship_id
    rt_field = geo_place_id
    rt_field = age
    rt_field = gender
    rt_field = only_with_avatar
    rt_field = only_with_portfolio
    rt_field = only_with_wage
    rt_field = visible
    rt_field = status
    rt_field = updated_at
    rt_field = about_me
    rt_field = fio
    rt_field = work_permit_ids
    rt_field = prof_area_ids
    rt_field = driver_license_ids
    rt_field = skills
    rt_field = employment_ids
    rt_field = schedule_ids
    rt_field = education_ids
    rt_field = contacts
    rt_field = language_codes
    rt_field = experience_text
    rt_field = portfolio_text
    rt_field = course_text

    rt_attr_string = post
    rt_attr_uint = wage
    rt_attr_uint = currency_id
    rt_attr_uint = tariff_rate_id
    rt_attr_uint = business_trip_id
    rt_attr_uint = work_experience_id
    rt_attr_uint = citizenship_id
    rt_attr_uint = geo_place_id
    rt_attr_uint = age
    rt_attr_uint = gender
    rt_attr_uint = only_with_avatar
    rt_attr_uint = only_with_portfolio
    rt_attr_uint = only_with_wage
    rt_attr_uint = visible
    rt_attr_uint = status
    rt_attr_uint = updated_at
    rt_attr_string = about_me
    rt_attr_string = fio
    rt_attr_string = work_permit_ids
    rt_attr_string = prof_area_ids
    rt_attr_string = driver_license_ids
    rt_attr_string = skills
    rt_attr_string = employment_ids
    rt_attr_string = schedule_ids
    rt_attr_string = education_ids
    rt_attr_string = contacts
    rt_attr_string = language_codes
    rt_attr_string = experience_text
    rt_attr_string = portfolio_text
    rt_attr_string = course_text

    rt_mem_limit = 512M

    morphology      = stem_enru
    charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+401->U+0435, U+451->U+0435
    min_prefix_len = 3
    index_exact_words = 1
    expand_keywords = 1
}
```

and it's here combine both indexs in one:

```
index jobResume
{
    type = distributed
    local = jobResumeIndex
    local = jobResumeRT
}
```

then when I trying insert new record:

```
mysql> insert into jobResumeRT  values(119,'Инженер - инспектор по безопасности полетов',0,190,193,7,15,0,538560,'14',1,1,0,0,1,2,'1575616137','','Иван Иванов ','','12,211','','{1057369: PHP (PHP4, PHP5, PHP5.5, HPHP)}','1','10','1234567898','','','','','');

ERROR 1064 (42000): row 1, column 3: string expected
```

third field currency_id must be an integer type, why string expected? I don't understand(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly RT indexes DON'T have a 'source'. They contain the data directly, not loading from a remote source. It might not be an erorr to specify `source=`, but will be ignored

RT indexes create their schema, from the `rt_field` and the `rt_attr_*` directives.

---

As such the schema **won't** be the same as the local/disk index. Will usually be same order as defined in index defintion, but can vary (if index has undergone edits)

... best to run a `DESCRIBE jobResumeRT` to find the actual order of all the columns in the index. Then when doing an `INSERT` etc without naming the columns, insert the columns in **same** order as returned from DESCRIBE.

Or do an insert, by naming the columns in the command, in same order. This may actually be better, as can then insert into a string attribute and field at once.